# Verifying if content has been shared on Facebook

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

I was given a requirement where the user of a site shares content on Facebook and gets points in return. This doesn't seem technically possible at the moment as content is shared through the addthis web site. Is there a way I could detect if some content has been shared on a wall, on the wall of a friend or at least whether someone has clicked on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the JavaScript SDK, this is possible (example from [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/)):

```
FB.ui(
   {
     method: 'feed',
     name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
     link: 'http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
     picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
     caption: 'Reference Documentation',
     description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.',
     message: 'Facebook Dialogs are easy!'
   },
   function(response) {
     if (response && response.post_id) {
       alert('Post was published.');
     } else {
       alert('Post was not published.');
     }
   }
 );
```

From there, instead of `alert`ing that the post was published or not, you could set a form variable or make an AJAX request to let the server know what happened.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Would this be considered as a bad practise or not? I'm just wondering why the question got downvoted. The site owner's idea here is to automatically reward users with points for anything that helps the site.

Comment: It probably got downvoted because it's already been asked. As far as bad practice, it's sort of a gray area on against the ToS - you're not allowed to incentivize shares, so there would need to be a way for users to get those points without sharing too. That said, we certainly track this information to see how well our share pages are performing and if there are things we can tweak.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the Facebook graph API? You can make your own buttons for the user to share with, and say "if you share using this button" to give them points.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/

You can also look at FBML.

Comment: Yes, I've been reading though various documentation on facebook about integration and making applications. Your suggestion is a good one but there will be no failsafe against users hitting the share button repeatedly and hitting cancel.